# Any @BatchSize annotation in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, batch-processing

I see Hibernate contains an optimization for lazy loaded associations using **@BatchSize**.
I'm trying to use this annotation in a JPA Project however, Eclipse does not recognize this annotation when using WildFly libraries. Is this annotation available also in JPA or it's just peculiar of Hibernate?
Thanks

Comment: This annotation is presumably in your chosen JPA provider's package, i.e a vendor extension. Why not look it up in the docs of that JPA provider, and what it says about its applicability?